# fetch all values of an array and display in a table

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

How do I display the values of the array `isReferralAvailable` from firestore. Here is the visual representation of my google firestore

[image]

and here is my code for fetching I only have trouble on how to fetch the values of `isReferralAvailable` of every document under the collection of `ReferralCodes`

```
const [referralCodes, setReferralCodes] = useState([]);
const [usedReferralCodes, setUsedReferralCodes] = useState([]);


useEffect(() => {
    onSnapshot(collection(db, "ReferralCodes"), (docsSnap) => {
      setReferralCodes(
        docsSnap.docs.map((doc) => ({
          ...doc.data()["isReferralAvailable"],
          id: doc.id,
        }))
      );
      setUsedReferralCodes(
        docsSnap.docs.map((doc) => ({
          ...doc.data()["isReferralUsed"],
          id: doc.id,
        }))
      );
    });
  }, []);
```

and this is my table row and mapping the `referralCodes` and `usedReferralCodes` however I am having trouble since the keys are index and I not know how to display them..

```
<tr className="bg-white border-b dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700">
                    {/* mapping the available codes */}
                    {referralCodes.map((codes) => {
                      return (
                        <td className="px-6 py-4 font-medium text-gray-900 whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white">
                          {codes[1]}{" "}
                        </td>
                      );
                    })}
    
                    {/* mapping the used codes */}
                    {usedReferralCodes.map((usedCodes) => {
                      return (
                        <td className="px-6 py-4 font-medium text-gray-900 whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white">
                          {usedCodes[1]}{" "}
                        </td>
                      );
                    })}
                    {usedReferralCodes.map((usedCodes) => {
                      return (
                        <td className="px-6 py-4 font-medium text-gray-900 whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white">
                          {usedCodes[1]}{" "}
                        </td>
                      );
                    })}
                  </tr>
```

and this results of displaying only the `index 1` of every document that have a `isReferralAvailable` I want to display everything under the array field of `isReferralAvailable` in table row. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `map()` function in javascript takes a callback, which can have the following arguments:

`element`: The current element being processed in the array.

`index`: The index of the current element being processed in the array.

So in your case, what you can do is use the `index` to access every element in the array:

```
 {referralCodes.map((codes,key) => {
   return (
       <td className="px-6 py-4 font-medium text-gray-900 whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white">
        {codes[key]}{" "}
       </td>
     );
  })}
```

Check here for more info:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Hello, I have tried your solution. However, I cannot fetch all the values still on all ``isReferralAvailable`` on different document fields. Here's a screenshot of what I console log with the solution you offered [link](https://prnt.sc/2brDK05qh7OD). Thank you!

Comment: @flutternewbiee something like this then: https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-wozniak-1wxt6b